# Are databases stored in SSD or in RAM ,

Tags: database, storage, nosql

So, I have an app wich use NoSql "CouchDB" as a database. We are having around 30k of json docs, each doc has less than 1kb of data .

Our plan currently has 512 RAM and 20 gb of SSD storage . I was wondering whether databases were stored on RAM or on SSD, while the app is running ?

Because having the whole database in ram would make the whole app very slow, given that we have other cron jobs + the running app itself .

Comment: Actually, you are wrong there. Having it in RAM makes it about 100 times faster (because access is about 100 times faster to RAM than SSD).

Answer (score -1):

CouchDB database files are getting stored on SSD Storage and not RAM.

Comment: Not exactly. It depends on configuration and utilization of features. For example, [batch mode](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/performance.html#batch).